# R Regression with robust standard errors has same results

Tags: r, regression

I am doing a Regression in R and because the Breusch Pagan Test indicates Heteroscedasticity, I am calculating the data with robust standard errors.

```
M1b <- lm(Lifetime_CO2 ~ wsignatory + wequity_dummy + wloan_dummy+
  wloan_dummy:wsignatory + Capacity_mw + forthcoming + cut_off +
  retire_until_2050 + retire_after_2050 + wfinancing, data = data_all)
summary(M1b) 
M1bR <- coeftest(M1b, vcov = vcov(M1b, type = "HC0"))
```

strangely enough, I get exactly the same results as when I calculate without the robust standard errors. Is that possible or do I make a mistake?